# How to install a driver for the HP Deskjet 5550 on macOS 10.14?

Tags: macos, printing, driver

I want to print in color from an old HP Deskjet 5550 printer (17 years old and works without an issue, I heard).

- macOS offers *Generic PCL Laser Printer* for this device. It works (although it is not a laser printer), but only in black & white.
- The old individual driver on the HP website doesn't work with macOS 10.14
- *Mac Printer Driver 5.1* (dated 20 September 2019 on HP website https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Deskjet-5500-Printer-series/71895/model/71897, dated 2017 on the Apple website https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1888?locale=en_US) doesn't contain a driver for this model, as seen in `/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources` and in the dialogue when adding a new printer.

What are my options?

Comment: I used a driver from the "HP deskjet 5400 series" now. By its design, it seems to be a different inkjet printer, but it works more or less (the first sheet isn't printed on and you have to press some button on the printer). I would be however still be interested how to install the correct driver, as I have to print from it from time to time.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201465 says it's supported natively. I've a much newer HP which needs HP's own suite to enable full print/scan functionality, but 'just printing' should work without.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can’t find the Deskjet 5550 on the list.

Comment: ah… D5500 series, might be different

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Gutenprint drivers:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-print/files/

Click the "Download Latest Version" button.

Once you have downloaded the disk image and installed the drivers, make sure the printer is connected and powered up, then re-add your printer in System Preferences > Printer & Scanners.  It should automatically select the Gutenprint driver.  Otherwise, manually select it.

Click "Add" and you are ready to print.